strange coil effect in Falstad
I was just using Falstad to create a circuit and while I was trying something I noticed this. When I close and open the switch back to back it was supposed to create a curve. But turns out it's only doing it when I close the circuit. Current goes directly to the zero when I open the switch.
Is it a bug or it's supposed to be like this in real life too?


What do you expect then and why? Falstad does not emulate switches that arc over with near infinite voltage while current falls to zero.

Maybe try paralleling the switch with a few hundred kΩ.

Kaan, if we are done here, please take note of this: What should I do when someone answers my question. If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.


Is it a bug or it's supposed to be like this in real life too ?

It happens pretty much like this in real life. I mean, if you open a switch in series with an inductor, how can you expect the current to benignly glide back towards zero amps through an open-circuit?

Current goes directly to the zero when I open the switch

In real life it will generate a several kV spark that keeps the current flowing but for a very short period of time.
